# Two factor authentication & Bitvise

Tags: windows, ssh

On my server, Google two-factor authentication is up&running. I can login with the  CLI from my desktop-ubuntu to the server. So, it's working.

However, how can i login under Windows with the program Bitvise? I tried different authentication-settings (on the first tab), but couldn't find the right one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple: in the box Authentication (on the first tab), fill in the Username. Set Initial method on 'keyboard-interactive' and ***remove*** the content in the field Submethods.

When login in, BitVise asks for the credentials. Now i only have to find out how to store the password.